# Costum Pipe makes image endless loop (blinking)

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I have some data to show and data look like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Od-QC4xpfXXH4UgKDPkhkB90DQMUDAhV

Code:

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let item of content | sortprogram: 'month'">
   <ion-item>{{item.key}}</ion-item>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-3 col-md-4 col-xl-12 *ngFor="let content of item.value | slice:0:limit; let i=index">
         <img (click)="goView(content)" src="{{content.thumbnail_image}}" />
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

and it keeps looping  on image actually because of custom pipe.

How can I stop the looping?

I'm using like `groupby` pipe. But if I don't use custom pipe it works well.

And this is my `groupby` pipes:

```
transform(value: Array<any>, field: string): Array<any>{ 

    if(!value || !value.length) { return value; } 

    const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur)=> { 

        if(!prev[cur[field]]) { 
            prev[cur[field]] = [cur]; 
        } else { 
            prev[cur[field]].push(cur); 
        } return prev; 

    }, {}); 

    return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] 

}));
```

Comment: Please, always edit your post and add code blocks correctly indented instead of adding them as comment.

Comment: thx for your help. i got error when i do that so i post it as a comment.

Comment: Okay. No problem. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid duplicate object names. You use `content` twice. Maybe this is the main problem here. I replaced it with `element`. Please check.

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let item of content | sortprogram: 'month'">
    <ion-item>{{item.key}}</ion-item>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-3 col-md-4 col-xl-12 
               *ngFor="let element of item.value | slice:0:limit; let i=index">
                <img (click)="goView(element)" src="{{element.thumbnail_image}}" />
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: Oh i missed that little thing. Ok ill try it first. Thank you

Comment: sorry Lynx 242, is not working tho, what should i do? i think because the return of the pipes.

Comment: Sorry, but then I have no further idea.

Comment: Then i have to make my api like group by mode ?